# inflate view in user's home/active screen

Tags: android

Could someone kindly share how to inflate a `View` to user's home (or active) screen, like this image :

[image]

The `Any.do` application can inflate a `View` on the bottom of my home (or active) screen (the `View` still inflated even when im playing game) and at the same time displaying a notification.

How to accomplish this? I tried to google but cant get a clue.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

It's a  TYPE_TOAST PopuWindow.

https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-UCToast

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But i dont think its a `PopupWindow`

Comment: Why?You can do anything in popuWindow.